# Get the default number of elements per leaf in a Decision Tree of Spark MLlib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, decision-tree

I want to get the default number of elements per leaf in a Spark MLlib Decision Tree, if it is possible.

I've been reading here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html and also trying to find something in https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/tree/model/Node.scala but I couldn't find the information that I need.

I know about the `minInstancesPerNode` Strategy parameter, but isn't what I want.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could explain what do you exactly mean with "default number of elements per leaf"? Are you talking of a trained/fitted model?

Comment: I mean if there is a default number of instances in each leaf of the Decision Tree, because I know there is a minimun, but how about the average number of instances? or if there is more information than only the `minInstancesPerNode` regarding to each leaf.. I hope to be clear this time, if not please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Spark `DecisionTreeClassifier` has several parameters that you can set with `setZYZ` methods before training time. A number of methods will help you regularizing the tree and avoiding overfitting. e.g.

- `setMinInstancesPerNode`: The minimum number of training records that have to be present in a node/leaf to be valid. The the node/leaf has less than minInstances it will be rolled up into the parent
- `setMaxDepth`: The maximum depth of the tree after which the tree will stop growing.
- `setMinInfoGain`: The minimum information gain for a split to occur

Once you train (`.fit`) a Spark decision tree and then predict (`.transform`) you will have 3 additional columns in your DataFrame (for classification):

- `predictionCol`: "Predicted label"
- `rawPredictionCol`: "Vector of length # classes, with the counts of training instance labels at the tree node which makes the prediction"
- `probabilityCol`: "Vector of length # classes equal to rawPrediction normalized to a multinomial distribution"

The column `rawPredictionCol` might be what you are looking for. It tells you how many instances of each class ended up in the leaf after building the tree at training time. The predicted label is the class with the highest count. The `probabilityCol` (derived from `rawPredictionCol`) captures the "confidence" in the prediction. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#output-columns